# (R) Error in cspade > summary(s1) : comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, arules

I try to execute the SPADE algorithm (arules and arulesSequences package) for sequential pattern mining.

If I run the code

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(arulesSequences)

x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki.txt", package = "arulesSequences"), info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))
  as(x, "data.frame")

s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
cspade> summary(s1)
```

as it is specified in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE

I receive the following error:

```
Error in cspade > summary(s1) : 
   comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Small note: by downloading the packages the hole code will work for you because it uses example data.

Does somebody has an idea how to solve the error?

Best Regards,
Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution. It was a simple mistake. Instead of

```
cspade> summary(s1)
```

I (now obviously) should have written:

```
summary(s1)
```

... a beginners mistake.